Deciphering Antwerp Police Immigration Files document in French
I need help with deciphering handwriting on an old French language document from the Antwerp Police Files. The person in question is my great-grandmother.
The file is this one:
https://www.familysearch.org/records/images/image-details?place=2092&startDate=1884-01-01&endDate=1884-12-31&lifeEvent=127180&lifeEventRecordTypes=123632,124162,127023&page=1&rmsId=TH-1961-28169-22260-20&imageIndex=600&singleView=true
file 54635
page  602 (left)
I have deciphered what is on the front page (601 right), what I am trying to figure out is on the second page (602). Here is what I know, I need help filling in blanks and answering some questions:
7: date of arrival in Belgium:
1st time 1884, second time February 1908
8: Previous Residence in Belgium
Antwerp from 1884 - 1890  do I have this right?
??????????????????? rue de la bois 26
9 date of arrival in the town/suburb
1st time 1884, second time February 1908
10 nature of identification papers
birth certificate from bernkastel (but what is the date and how is it relevant because it's not her birth date) is this the date she got the certificate?
11 political refugee
no
12 history of good conduct or something like this
?????
13 plans on staying longer than 6 months
not sure what she says here
14 other notes or comments
??
The rest of the file is about her other family.
Question

She arrived in Feb 1908, yet the document is dated Nov 1908.
is there a reason for this delay? or is this an exit document of sorts?
I am trying to trace her movements because in 1909 she boarded a boat in England and I'm trying to figure out how/when/why she went to England.

if I understand correctly about from 1884-1890  - where did she go in 1890. Or is it from 1890 at rue de la bois (where her mom still stays in 1908 according to page 1)



Is there a Link that doesn't demand membership, please?

Hi Robbie, thanks for responding. The familsearch records require only login, no subscription. I am not sure how to share it in another way.

Oh, I see. Then unless it breaks your membership terms, or is too much, might screen shots work?

Aaah OK, didn't think of this. Here are the screenshots:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/gtmmt34y7lpua5pf4bc7n/AAUf1WYmDIZzW3PsXK5V58k?rlkey=lf8v4gkr19l4jzd26hlhc0x7f&st=8ab75nzj&dl=0

Thanks and in those shots, is the problem deciphering the hand-writing, or what, please?

What I think I have managed to understand, and what I am unclear about, is in my post

Then good luck with it!

But so you are unable to help me figure out the blanks?

I'm so sorry to say, that's clearly true. Very simply, I can't see the blanks. The images you Posted have too little resolution to be useful. Logging in might access more detail but how can that happen?
